# When can bit shifting cause undefined behaviour

Tags: c

I tried finding a good answer who list all possibilities(maybe there is only one?).

So considering both signed and unsigned numbers, which are the ways to cause UB with bit shifting in C?

Comment: There's only two cases: shifting (any direction) by the width of the type or more; and shifting a 1 into the sign bit

Comment: @M.M So it’s not legal to shift to much even on unsigned types?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that question sorry

Comment: It depends how much you mean by too much. For example, given `uint32_t u`, `u << n` and `u >> n` are UB if `n` is `32` or larger. `u << 31` and `u >> 31` are fine, though, no matter what value `u` has.

Comment: @Fredrik yes, shifting more than the operand's width is undefined regardless of signness, because some old processors just return 0 for big shifts, while others just leave data in an undefined state, therefore the standard couldn't specify a fixed behavior for all of them. Modern architectures just mask the low 4/5/6... bits depending on the left operand's size

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: It took me quite some time to realize that an unsigned 32 bit value shifted left 32 positions does not give a zero ;-) There's no good logical reasoning for it, but Intel designed it's CPU's that way (in 16 bit CPUs the shift width was four bits, so 16 would be equal 0).

Comment: @U.Windl obviously there's a reason to that: checking if the width >= 32 and returns zero needs a comparator and is a lot more complex than simply taking the low 5 bits. That's why all modern architectures do that, not only x86. In the past there are even architectures that shift left or right depending on the signness of the shift count. 8086 also doesn't mask the shift count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C99 standard says this about bitwise shift operators (emphasis added, and `^` is used to represent exponentiation):

> **§6.5.7.3**: The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.  The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.**
>   **§6.5.7.4**: The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the  result is `E1 × 2^E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in  the result type.  If `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1 × 2^E2`
>   is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
>   **§6.5.7.5**: The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If
>   `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a non-negative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1 / 2^E2`. **If `E1` has  a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.**

So, to summarise, behaviour is undefined if any of the following are true:

- the right operand is signed and negative, or
- the right operand is greater than or equal to the width of the left operand (after promotion), or
- the left operand is signed and negative, or
- a left shift is performed and the left operand is signed and the resultant value is not representable as a signed integer

Comment: What actually happens in practice if the right-hand argument is negative?

Comment: @JL2210 most modern processors just mask the low 5 or 6 bits (or another number depending on the left operand size) so for example `5 << -1` and `5 << -2` will become `5 << 31` and `5 << 30` respectively (for a 32-bit register)

Comment: *"behaviour is undefined if any of the following are true: ... the left operand is signed and negative, or"* This is not *undefined behaviour*, it provides *implementation defined* value as written in your quotation. They are different things.